# Could not connect to SoapClient with SSL self-signed certificate

Tags: php, ssl, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to connect to a soap interface with PHP's SoapClient. I can connect with it through SoapUI or with openssl s_client on the command line.

Server info:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
```

If I try it with PHP (7.1) it keeps saying (exception SoapFault):

> Could not connect to host

Code:

```
$soap = new \SoapClient(storage_path('local_wsdl.wsdl'), [
            'location' => 'https://correct-url:port/endpoint',
            'trace' => true,
            'local_cert' => storage_path('local-cert.pfx'),
            'passphrase' => 'cert-password',
            'exceptions' => true,
            'user_agent' => 'PHP WS',
            'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
                'ssl' => [
                    'verify_peer'       => false,
                    'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true,
                ]
            ]),
        ]);
```

With openssl:  openssl s_client -crlf -connect domain:port
result:

```
// some other data

SSL handshake has read 8163 bytes and written 370 bytes
Verification: OK

// some other data

New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    Session-ID: the-session-id
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: the-master-key
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1513608735
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
```

Both commands are run by the same command line on the server. The certificate is also added to the ca-certificates

How can I make the request work?